# I have to collect unique symbols from a set of cards in JAVA. But while giving the inputs, I am not able to get unique results

Tags: java, collections, set, unique

This is the code that I have tried.
But Set is storing all the values and does not remove duplicates.
What am I doing wrong and how to I modify it?
I have used List just for the do while loop as while using contains() in Set was showing an error.How do i remove it to make it more efficient?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<Card> set = new TreeSet<>();
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        boolean flag;

        do {
            Card c  = new Card();
            System.out.println("Enter a card: ");
            c.setSymbol(sc.nextLine().trim().charAt(0));
            c.setNumber(sc.nextInt());
            sc.nextLine();
            set.add(c);
            count++;
            list.add(c.symbol);
            if(list.contains('a') && list.contains('b') && list.contains('c') && list.contains('d')){
                flag =false;
            }else {
                flag = true;
            }

        }while(flag);


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Four symbols gathered in "+count+" Cards.");
        System.out.println("Cards in Set are: ");

        for(Card ca:set) {
            System.out.println(ca.getSymbol()+" "+ca.getNumber());
        }
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Output should be:

```
Enter a card :
a 1
Enter a card :
a 2 
Enter a card :
d 6
Enter a card :
c 2
Enter a card :
d 1
Enter a card :
c 1
Enter a card :
b 2
Four symbols gathered in 8 cards.
Cards in Set are : 
a 1 
b 2 
c 2 
d 6
```

Comment: What output are you getting? And what output are you expecting exactly? Why should a 1 be printed and not a 2? Is it because it occurs first?

Comment: How is the Card class implemented?

Comment: I am getting all the card details I enter. If I enter a 1 first and then a 2, then only a 1 should be printed as 'a' is a duplicate value. Shouldn't Set take care of that? @VSS CHAITANYA Chavali

Comment: public class Card implements Comparable<Card>{
 public char symbol;
 private int number;
 
 public char getSymbol() {
  return symbol;
 }
 public int getNumber() {
  return number;
 }
 public void setSymbol(char s) {
  symbol = s;
 }
 public void setNumber(int n) {
  number = n;
 }

 @Override
 public int compareTo(Card o) {
  return (this.symbol>o.symbol)? 1:-1;

 }
 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store items which have unique partial data (card symbol here) instead of unique items (cards here), you are better off with Map than with Set.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Character,Card> map = new TreeMap<>();
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        boolean flag;

        do {
            Card c  = new Card();
            System.out.println("Enter a card: ");
            c.setSymbol(sc.nextLine().trim().charAt(0));
            c.setNumber(sc.nextInt());
            sc.nextLine();
    if(!map.containsKey(c.symbol))
                 map.put(c.symbol,c);
            count++;
            list.add(c.symbol);
            if(list.contains('a') && list.contains('b') && list.contains('c') && list.contains('d')){
                flag =false;
            }else {
                flag = true;
            }

        }while(flag);


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Four symbols gathered in "+count+" Cards.");
        System.out.println("Cards in Set are: ");

        for(char ch:map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(ch+" "+map.get(ch).getNumber());
        }
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

I just wanted the code to look more like your code. Otherwise, you can also get rid of the ArrayList and check for contains on the map itself.

**EDIT 1:**

I don't know about your `Card` class but if it is a custom class defined by you, then you can just override the`compareTo` method in that class according to your need. You can add the following methods in the `Card` class.

```
boolean compareTo(Card c){
    if(this.getsymbol()==c.getSymbol())
        return 0;

    return this.getsymbol()>c.getSymbol()?1:-1;
}
```

Your set considers two cards as different always(you are never returning 0 in your `compareTo`). This `compareTo` definition will stop the Set from accepting two cards with same symbol.

Comment: ThankYou. It is working. But can it be done using set?

Comment: @Pranay Kankariya I have edited my answer. If you found my answer helpful, please consider making it as the correct answer.